# how to print this php array?

Tags: php, arrays

In Facebook API, I have this array.

```
{
"id": "587967941220651", 
"about": "", 
"can_post": true, ...
```

And I printed this array like this.

```
$request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '/PAGE_NAME' );
$response = $request->execute();
// get response
$graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();
// print profile data
echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';
```

In my web page, I got this results.

```
Array
(
[id] => 587967941220651
[about] =>
[can_post] => 1 ...
```

And this time, I have this kind of array.

```
{
"data": [
{
  "id": "1444336682520148_1458726944414455", 
  "from": {
    "id": "1444336682520148", 
    "name": "James"
  }, 
  "story": "James shared Kevin's status update.",
```

As you see, there is "data" in the very front. How can I print this kind of array?
Thank you.

Comment: can't you print `$graphObject['data']`?

Comment: `print_r($graphObject)`. You will probably find a structure where `'data'` is a numeric-indexed array. So You are ultimately looking for the contents in `$graphObject['data'][0]`, or loop over multiples: `foreach ($graphObject['data'] as $item) { echo $item['can_post']; //etc... }`

Comment: When I use print($graphObject['data']);, I get  Undefined index: data in /var/www/html/c.php

Comment: You have a JSON array, you need to run `json_decode($graphObject, true)` then dump the output from the decode.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25354859/i-cant-get-any-value-from-php-facebook-graph-api
This is the problem, guys.