# I can't get any value from php Facebook graph api

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is my full code.

```
// include required files form Facebook SDK

require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookHttpable.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurl.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/HttpClients/FacebookCurlHttpClient.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/AccessToken.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/Entities/SignedRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSession.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRedirectLoginHelper.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequest.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookResponse.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookSDKException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookRequestException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookOtherException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/FacebookAuthorizationException.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphObject.php' );
require_once( 'Facebook/GraphSessionInfo.php' );

use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookHttpable;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurl;
use Facebook\HttpClients\FacebookCurlHttpClient;
use Facebook\Entities\AccessToken;
use Facebook\Entities\SignedRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\FacebookResponse;
use Facebook\FacebookSDKException;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookOtherException;
use Facebook\FacebookAuthorizationException;
use Facebook\GraphObject;
use Facebook\GraphSessionInfo;

// start session
session_start();

// init app with app id and secret
FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication( 'KEY','SECRET' );

// login helper with redirect_uri
$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper( 'SITE_NAME.php' );

// see if a existing session exists
if ( isset( $_SESSION ) && isset( $_SESSION['fb_token'] ) ) {
  // create new session from saved access_token
  $session = new FacebookSession( $_SESSION['fb_token'] );

  // validate the access_token to make sure it's still valid
  try {
    if ( !$session->validate() ) {
      $session = null;
    }
  } catch ( Exception $e ) {
    // catch any exceptions
    $session = null;
  }
}  

if ( !isset( $session ) || $session === null ) {
  // no session exists

  try {
    $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
  } catch( FacebookRequestException $ex ) {
    // When Facebook returns an error
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  } catch( Exception $ex ) {
    // When validation fails or other local issues
    // handle this better in production code
    print_r( $ex );
  }

}

// see if we have a session
if ( isset( $session ) ) {

  // save the session
  $_SESSION['fb_token'] = $session->getToken();
  // create a session using saved token or the new one we generated at login
  $session = new FacebookSession( $session->getToken() );

  // graph api request for user data
  $request = new FacebookRequest( $session, 'GET', '***/1458726944414455/likes***' );
  $response = $request->execute();
  // get response
  $graphObject = $response->getGraphObject()->asArray();

  // print profile data
  echo '<pre>' . print_r( $graphObject, 1 ) . '</pre>';

  // print logout url using session and redirect_uri (logout.php page should destroy the session)
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLogoutUrl( $session, 'SITE_NAME/logout.php' ) . '">Logout</a>';

} else {
  // show login url
  echo '<a href="' . $helper->getLoginUrl( array( 'email', 'user_friends' ) ) . '">Login</a>';
}
```

In *** *** section above, if I put some Facebook page names or 'me', the code works fine. But when I insert '/1458726944414455/likes' something like this, I can't get any value so the results are always like this
    Array ( )

What makes me mad is, /1458726944414455/likes this works fine in https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer, which is Graph API explorer. I think token scope is not that different in Graph API explorer and my own website.

What is wrong? I searched every website which wrote about facebook php sdk or graph api, but they are using almost same code with me.

Is this because that I didn't do anything about Review Submission Form? I just using the default App Status & Review. But I thought that it doesn't matter because I don't do login with Facebook something like that. What is wrong? Please help me.

Thank you for reading.

Comment: in your case, it might be the permissions that you are requesting.  I see email and user_friends (that's in your login link).  There may be some other permissions you need in order to get likes.  Look in the Facebook Graph API Explorer by clicking get access token.  You'll see a pop-up and you can select specific permissions to test against.